# How to run the flask app in the path of domain?

Tags: flask

I want to run the flask app in "mysite.com/flask". so i set the proxy in apache config file

```
<Location "/flask">
                ProxyPreserveHost On
                ProxyPass "http://localhost:8000"
                ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:8000"
</Location>
```

how to make the `url_for()` or `redirect()` to return the path relative to 'mysite.com/flask'.

i have set the root path in flask

```
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/flask'
```

but ,it's don't work.`return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))` .it's redirect to 'mysite.com/dashboard'.
how to make it redirect to 'mysite.com/flask/dashboard'